# Is it possible to use Il2CppDumper on android?

Tags: android

Recently I lost my computer, where I used a lot Il2CppDumper to dump lib2cpp, but now I can not, because I have only cell phone, if anyone has any know some way to use it on mobile I am grateful

Project Link: https://github.com/Perfare/Il2CppDumper

Comment: How is this a programming/coding issue?

Comment: You could try to run it with wine for Android.